# GDAL predicator and Tile Offsets

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, bigtiff

I would like to "shift" the origin of a BigTIFF file. But is is not so easy. So instead, I try to use gdal_translate to create a new file. But when I compare the original file and the shifted one, I can see, that I loose the "Predictor option and the "Tile Offsets ".
My command is
`gdal_translate -co PREDICATOR=2  -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE  -co BIGTIFF=YES -of GTiff -a_ullr 531068.9508 8584958.7557954 531254.9456 8584793.017 input.tif out.tif`

PREDICATOR of input.tif is Horizontal differencing
Tile Offsets of input.tif is Binary data 7785 bytes

PREDICATOR of out.tif is None
Tile Offsets of out.tif is Binary data 28718 bytes

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Check spelling and use `PREDICTOR` https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html

> PREDICTOR=[1/2/3]: Set the predictor for LZW, DEFLATE and ZSTD
> compression. The default is 1 (no predictor), 2 is horizontal
> differencing and 3 is floating point prediction. PREDICTOR=2 is only
> supported for 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit samples (support for 64 bit was
> added in libtiff > 4.3.0). PREDICTOR=3 is only supported for 16, 32
> and 64 bit floating-point data.

But generally speaking it would be much better to edit the metadata of the existing TIFF than to create a new copy. Use gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html#gdal-edit

```
gdal_edit -a_ullr 531068.9508 8584958.7557954 531254.9456 8584793.017 input.tif
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution !